# Potential problems with arithmetic operations mixing char and double?

Tags: c

I'm very new to C and I'm writing a Ruby C Extension. One of the functions should compute a bland between two colours. The `Color` struct uses `char` to store the RGB values. The blending ratio is a `double` between 0.0 and 1.0.

Is it bad practice to mix `char` and `double` in an operation I have done here? Could there be potential problems?

I'm guessing that if weight is not between 0.0 and 1.0 the could be problems as it might result in a value smaller than 0 or larger than 255.

Should I be explicitly casting types?

```
typedef struct Color    Color;

static struct Color {
  unsigned char red, green, blue, alpha;
};


static Color
color_blend(  Color color1, Color color2, double weight )
{
  Color color3 = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };

  color3.red    = ( 1 - weight ) * color1.red   + ( weight * color2.red );
  color3.green  = ( 1 - weight ) * color1.green + ( weight * color2.green );
  color3.blue   = ( 1 - weight ) * color1.blue  + ( weight * color2.blue );
  color3.alpha  = ( 1 - weight ) * color1.alpha + ( weight * color2.alpha );

  return color3;
}
```

Comment: the right hand expression is "promoted" to `double` and then converted back to `byte` when assigned. the question to answer is: can this cast loose information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't **need** to perform explicit casting; the compiler's implicit casting should do the same thing.  However, there are two good reasons to consider explicit casts:

1. On higher warning levels, you may get warning messages about loss of precision etc. for implicit casts.
2. Explicit casts help document your intent to readers of your code.

I don't think there will be any range issues with your code.  However, you might consider adding round-to-nearest behaviour, as currently a computed value of e.g. 99.999 will truncate to 99.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular example, it will work ok, as long as you don't change the expression in the future. There are so many implicit promotions going on in your code, so it is very easy to slip a bug in somewhere.

Let us dissect this row:

```
color3.red    = ( 1 - weight ) * color1.red   + ( weight * color2.red );
```

If we just look at the types used, this expression is equivalent to:

```
unsigned char = (signed int - double) * unsigned char + (double * unsigned char);
```

Lets assume that the compiler uses left-to-right order of evaluation. This expression would then be evaluated an calculated in the following manner:

```
unsigned char = (signed int - double) * unsigned char + (double * unsigned char);  //balance ->
unsigned char = (double - double) * unsigned char + (double * unsigned char); //calculate->
unsigned char = double * unsigned char + (double * unsigned char); //balance->
unsigned char = double * double + (double * unsigned char); //calculate->
unsigned char = double + (double * unsigned char); //balance->
unsigned char = double + (double * double); //calculate->
unsigned char = double + double; // calculate->
unsigned char = double; // truncate->
unsigned char = unsigned char;
```

If any sub-expression did not contain a double type, bugs would likely occur. It will be very dangerous to modify this expression, if you aren't aware of all the implicit type conversions. If you are uncertain about them, use explicit typecasts.

Coding standards like MISRA-C bans implicit conversions entirely, since such conversions are sometimes dangerous and unpredictable. A MISRA-C compliant version of your code would look like:

```
color3.red    = (double) ((1.0-weight) * color1.red) + 
                (double) (weight * color2.red);
```

(You are getting away from plenty of issues because you are using `unsigned char`, rather than plain `char`. Had you used `char`, then all bets would be off.)

Comment: Well knew that if I did not have any floating point types it'd all be integer arithmetics and the result would be wrong. But I was thinking that if I placed casts all over the place the code would not read as well as you'd get such long lines. But I was not sure if there was any other unforeseen issues due to my inexperience with C. This breakdown was very helpful.

Comment: Question is, is there a better practice for what I am doing? This function was the only one where I needed to mix `double` and `char` - and I didn't see any point in using `int` for the `Color` struct. While my function might be Ok - as people say, is there a better design?

Comment: @thomthom The important part is to look at each sub expression and understand what is going on there. Implicit promotions in C are complex and dangerous. [Good reading from CERT](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules) on this topic. (CERT C is a coding standard, basically a light version of MISRA-C, with more focus on desktop computers rather than critical systems.)

Answer (score 0):

To make it safe i think you should do next steps

```
unsigned char source_color = 230;
double coef = 0.7;
double res = source_color * coef; //is OK as char will be converted 
//to double before operation

if(res < 0)
     res = 0;
if(res > 255)
     res = 255;
//this is needet to prevent from such bug. 
//If you wan't to convert for example double(256) to char you will have char(1) 
//as it will be counted 256 % 255 as 255 is max char can fit

unsigned char result_color = (unsigned char)res; //This will trucate fraction 
//part of the number for example 1.2 => 1 or 1.999 => 1. 
//If you want to have 1.999 => 2 you should round you double number.
```

This solution is safe.

Comment: `unsigned char(res)` is invalid syntax in C, C doesn't have constructors. And even in C++ using the construction of a temporary instead of a cast is probably frowned upon. The "correct" ways in C are `(unsigned char)res` and in C++ `static_cast<unsigned char>(res)`.

Answer (score -1):

It's better if you don't use explicit casts in normal arithmetic. The compiler knows how to do  optimizations, and if you start telling it what types to use you might unwittingly rule out certain options and slow down your code.

Beware though, if you have something like this:

```
double_var = int_var1 / int_var2;
```

it will do *integer* division and *then* convert the result to double, so you'll get rounding errors. As long as one of the variables is floating-point type (as you have) it should work just fine though.

It's the same with constants: use `0.0`, rather than plain `0`, if you want floating-point maths.

Comment: Do you have a citation for your first paragraph?

Comment: No, not off hand, but I had a fun time trying to convince GCC to optimize widening multiplies on ARM last year, and it doesn't work if the types have been artificially widened or narrowed.